# GNOME Web (Epiphany) 3.36.1 will not render sites only on Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, 20.04, epiphany

Epiphany browser just straight up refuses to render sites that it works otherwise perfectly with on other OSes. The sites in question are Discord, where it just freezes up on the login page and won't render the QR code (which I believe is why it doesn't work, though this renders on other OSes) and Reddit, where it just froze. I've run it on Fedora 32 (running the same GTK and GNOME Shell theme) and Artix XFCE (running the same GTK theme as well) and these sites have worked just fine. I even tried the Flatpak, though not the Snap, and got the same results. I tested on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Lubuntu 20.04 and neither worked.

The thing is I have no idea where to even start with debug info. What do I collect to diagnose this? And why only Ubuntu? Is the version on Ubuntu outdated? I'm asking here because I'm fairly sure it's on Ubuntu's end.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit works okay for me in Web (Epiphany) 3.36.1 deb on Ubuntu GNOME 20.04.  I used incognito mode, Windscribe VPN, URL pay.reddit.com, I'm on kernel 5.4.0-38-generic, not sure if any of that is relevant.

Comment: I'm just straight regular mode with no VPN and whatever the latest kernel for Ubuntu is, tried all of chrome Firefox and safari user agents, also tried advertisements off. Discord in particular will not render on the login page for Ubuntu alone and thats the bigger concern to me.

Comment: At this point I believe Discord may have changed something on their backend so that only the latest version of GNOME Web - which Artix and Fedora would have but not Ubuntu - would still work with it. Midori stopped working with it too so its clearly an engine and imo pointing towards an outdated engine at that.